# ASP.NET CPU Spike related to high "% Time in GC" - what is a good baseline for ASP.NET?

Tags: asp.net

I have a situation where an ASP.NET application causes w3wp service cpu usage to spike to 100% while at the same time the "%time in GC" performance counters shows very high numbers 20-70%. This happens from time to time.

This all started happening after I upgraded to .NET 4.0 from 2.0, BTW.

I am looked at the performance counters, trying to get more clues, but I lack a good base line... what is "normal"?

- #Gen 0 Collections 10,000
- #Gen 1 Collections  4,700 (seems high)
- #Gen 2 collections  1,200 (again seems high)
- Finalization Survivors 5000  (is this high??)

To give you an idea of how busy the app is :

- ASP.NET Requests / Sec: 170
- ASP.NET Sessions Active: 900

On each page request, in my dev environment, Finalization Survivors is about 50. Seems high, but all the profiling tools I looked at, dont show anything out of ordinary...

I am looking for some baseline on what are the typical values for these params for a basic asp.net app. For example, how many "Finalization Survivors" are simply due to ASP.NET?

Many thanks!

**UPDATE - rolled back to .net 2.0 "fixed" the problem**

I have been struggling with this issue since morning, ever since I upgraded to .NET 4.0
I rolled back my chnages - set the website to use asp.net 2.0, rolled back some binaries that were compiled with .net 4.0 and all is beautiful now - no spikes, no long GC time, but still a heck of a lot of finalization survivors..

**UPDATE 2 - just switching to .NET 4.0 in IIS causes this slow down

I am updating this in case this is helpful to someone else one day who has the same problem. 
I found that the problems start just after switching IIS to use ASP.NET 4.0 on the website, without changing any of the .net 2.0 website code. I assumed, perhaps incorrectly, that it is backward compatible therefore a .net 2.0 website and resources it references should work fine under asp.net 4.0 but there appears to be some issue. If I get time to investigate further, I will update this with my findings

Comment: +1 Any more updates on this? I have a similar issue with Finalization Survivors (fluctuates between 164 - 575). I am simply using the Performance monitor of Win 7. I have a lot of object collections. What other parameter should I be interested? .NET 3.5 and win app.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest taking a look at [ANTS Performance Profiler](http://www.red-gate.com/products/dotnet-development/ants-performance-profiler/) and [ANTS Memory Profiler](http://www.red-gate.com/products/dotnet-development/ants-memory-profiler/) to see what might be causing the spike.

Comment: Yea I ANTS memory profiler is one of the tools I used BUT, I used it only on my dev and staging environment. was afraid to use them on production - is it safe for production use ?

Comment: It's not ideal, but you've got to get to the bottom of it somehow, right? It can't be worse than what's currently happening right? With the CPU spiking that high, anybody using the application will experience significant lags.

Answer (score 0):

I have seen that when reaching server capacity or a mass app pool recycle is happening.  Here is great article you can follow to identify bottlenecks:

[Chapter 17 — Tuning .NET Application Performance](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff647813.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

Check your disk space and how you Virtual memory and pagefile.sys is configured to expand. % time in GC may spike if you have very low disk space on the disk where you have placed the pagefile.sys. This is possibly because Least recently used Gen2 and LOH cant be paged as there is no space to expand and they occupy Ram leaving Gen1 and 2 to cram for space. This kicks in GC frequently and hence CPU spikes.